# Universal Link open URL after subdomain

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on universal link. I had some urls to open in my application.

I had added **portal.xyz.com** in associated domains.

**Problem** : My application opens on https://portal.xyz.com/. I want to continue this URL to browser. Just want to open URL that having start path https://portal.xyz.com/da/notification**.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to open up the app from the browser based on the URL Scheme defined in the app?

Comment: @Malik I had mentioned universal link not URL scheme. not only from browser but from anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep same associated domain in your project and you need to handle this case from apple-app-site-association file that you have uploaded in server,

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "apps": [],
      "details": [
          {
              "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.portal.xyz.com"//keep your Apple Id of you application,
              "paths": [ "/da/notification/*"]
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Hope it will be helpful.